# How to fix axis and add polygon to inset map in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, mapping

I'm trying to add a couple details to my map in ggplot2 but I'm new to the package and I'm not sure how to proceed. Code and map are below (ignore the weird spacing on the map, I took a screen shot in Rstudio). Thanks for taking a look!

I'm trying to do the following:

1. Add latitude and longitude tick marks on the x and y axis. I coded it in the script below but nothing is happening, not sure why - no errors pop up.
2. If possible, I'd like to add a box in the inset map showing the extent/coverage of the larger map, since the points in the smaller map (the red ones) are barely visible. I'm not sure how to add and place a polygon in the inset map.

Here is what the map currently looks like for reference:

[image: panama map]

```
library(raster)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
library(ggsn)
library(ggmap)
library(maps)
library(mapdata)

mapdata <- getData("GADM", country = "panama", level = 1)
mymap <- fortify(mapdata)

mypoint <- data.frame(long=c(-79.743, -79.696, -79.645, -79.595),
                      lat=c(9.160, 9.117, 9.058, 9.015),
                      group=c("L", "GW", "OGR", "LC"))
mypoint2 <- data.frame(long=c(-79.846, -79.707, -79.665, -79.610),
                      lat=c(9.181, 9.112, 9.057, 9.014),
                      group=c("BCI", "G", "EH", "MF"))

g1 <- ggplot() +
  geom_blank(data = mymap, aes(x=long, y=lat)) +
  geom_map(data = mymap, map = mymap, 
           aes(group = group, map_id = id),
           fill = "#b2b2b2", color = "black", size = 0.3) +
  coord_sf(xlim=c(-80,-79.5), ylim=c(8.9, 9.25), expand = FALSE) +
  geom_point(data = mypoint, aes(x = long, y = lat),
             color = "black", size = 3) +
  geom_label(data = mypoint, aes(label = group, x = long, y = lat), 
             size = 3, fontface = "bold", nudge_x = c(0.015, 0.02, 0.022, 0.018)) +
  geom_point(data = mypoint2, aes(x = long, y = lat),
             color = "blue", size = 3) +
  geom_label(data = mypoint2, aes(label = group, x = long, y = lat), 
             size = 3, fontface = "bold", nudge_x = c(-0.02, -0.018, -0.02, -0.02)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-80,-79.5), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(8.9, 9.25), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme_map() +
  ggsn::scalebar(location = "bottomleft", dist = 5,
                 transform = TRUE, dist_unit = "km", model = 'WGS84',           
                 x.min = -79.97, x.max = -79.8,
                 y.min = 8.93, y.max = 9.25) +
  north(x.min = -79.6, x.max = -79.5,
        y.min = 9.2, y.max = 9.24,
        location = "toprgiht", scale = 0.1)

g2 <- ggplotGrob(
  ggplot() +
    geom_polygon(data = mymap,
                 aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group),
                 fill = "#b2b2b2", color = "black", size = 0.3) +
    geom_point(data = mypoint, aes(x = long, y = lat),
               color = "red", size = 0.5) +
    coord_map("polyconic") +
    theme_map() +
    theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = NULL))
)     

g3 <- g1 +
  annotation_custom(grob = g2, xmin = -79.75, xmax = -79.51,
                    ymin = 8.9, ymax = 9.0)
g3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Latitude and longitude tick marks are disappearing because of `theme_map()` - it sets `axis_ticks` and `axis_text` (among other things) to `element_blank()`. One way to get them back is to override `theme_map()` with

```
g1_with_lbls <- g1 + 
  theme(
    axis.text = element_text(), 
    axis.ticks = element_line(),
    axis.title = element_text()
  ) +
  xlab("Longitude") +
  ylab("Lattitude")
```

2. You would place the polygon on the smaller map as a part of the `ggplotGrob` object you are creating

```
g2 <- ggplotGrob(
  ggplot() +
    geom_polygon(data = mymap,
                 aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group),
                 fill = "#b2b2b2", color = "black", size = 0.3) +
    geom_point(data = mypoint, aes(x = long, y = lat),
               color = "red", size = 0.5) +
    coord_map("polyconic") +
    theme_map() +
    theme(
      panel.background = element_rect(fill = NULL)
    ) +
    geom_rect(
      aes(xmin = -80, xmax = -79, ymin = 8.5, ymax = 9.5), fill = NA, 
      col = "red", size = 1
    )
)
```

Then

```
g3 <- g1_with_lbls +
  annotation_custom(grob = g2, xmin = -79.75, xmax = -79.51,
                    ymin = 8.9, ymax = 9.0)
g3
```

[image: plot with ticks and a rectangle]

Has both the ticks and the rectangle.

Comment: Awesome, that works perfectly! Thanks so much. If I wanted to label the axes with "Lat" and "Long" would I have to do something special as well? I tried adding in the standard "labs(y= "Latitude", x = "Longitude")" within the creation of g1 and g1_with_lbls, but it didn't come through either place.

Comment: `theme_map` also sets `axis.title` to `element_blank`. Set it to `element_text` for the axes titles to show. Updated the answer.

Comment: awesome, thanks. Is there an easy way to change the axis text from "lat" and "long" to the full words? I tried changing it all throughout my code, but it seems like it inherits "lat" and "long from the mapdata and mymap objects. I tried renaming the headers in the mymap df but it produces an error. thanks for all the help!

Comment: `xlab()` and `ylab()` functions will do that. Add them to the plot for which axes need to be labelled. Updated the answer.